# Cadastro via facebook api

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de saber como configurar o app do facebook para que ele possa receber os dados de qualquer usuario.. 
Eu tentei sem sucesso definindo esses 2 campos que o facebook me fornece:

```
FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "";
FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "";
```

Funcinou apenas com o meu login e com os outros dá esse erro:

> App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app
>   properly for Facebook Login.

(Configuração incorreta)

Estou tentado receber os dados do usuario, email, login, endereco..

Comment: Avalie o tutorial [Create An Asp.Net MVC 5 App With Facebook and...](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

Answer (score 2):

Conforme respondido pelo Luiz, existe o tutorial, e o que não é dito no tutorial é que será necessário enviar para **avaliação** uma aplicação web no facebook, no tutorial parece que é só criar a aplicação lá e pronto, mas não, terá que enviar com informações sobre a mesma (Logo, descrição, prints, etc...). Só depois de aprovada sua aplicação é que conseguirá utilizar o serviço do Facebook.

Mas siga o tutorial, inicie o processo.